# Show that the center of quaternions group $\textit{Q}$ is generated by the unique element with order 2.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, quaternions

$\textit{Q}$ is a group with order $8$, generated by $a,b$ where $a^4=1$, $b^2=a^2$ and $bab^{-1}=a^{-1}$.

I already proved that the unique element of $\textit{Q}$ with order $2$ is $a^2$.

How can I prove that $Z(\textit{Q})=\left<a^2\right>$?

Comment: You can just find, for each element $x$ not in the subgroup generated by $a^2$, an element $y$ such that $xy\ne yx$.

Comment: Slightly less direct, in a non-abelian group, the quotient over the center cannot be cyclic. So once you know the center has order at least 2, it cannot be any larger.

Comment: @verret I'm thinking about what you said...
For example, does exists a subgroup $H\leq Q$ isomorphic to $Q/Z(Q)?$
I tried to prove that such subgroup does not exists by the fact that $|Q|=|Q/Z(Q)| / |Z(Q)|$, but $|Z(Q)|=2$ implies $|Q/Z(Q)|=4$. Can I get a contradiction from here?

Comment: $Q/Z(Q)$ is isomorphic to the Klein group, and $Q$ has no such subgroup, so no, but I don't see how that is relevant.

Comment: The point is this: it's easy to see that $a^2\in Z(G)$, so the center has order at least $2$. If it was bigger, it would have order at least $4$, but then $G/Z(G)$ would have order at most $2$, so would be cyclic, but this implies the group is abelian, contradiction.

Comment: @verret this is not relevant for my question. This was just a thinking.

Comment: There are only $8$ elements. Check them all and see which are in the center.

Comment: For a first exposure to group, you should just brute force it. But with more concepts, and the $ijk$-presentation, $Q_8$ clearly has $S_3$ acting by automorphisms (permuting $i,j,k$), and $Z(Q_8)$ is a characteristic subgroup, which leaves only $\pm1$ as possible elements of the center.